# Google Calendar Desktop Notifications Disappear Now

Tags: windows, google-calendar

My calendar Event Settings notification is set on "Desktop notifications" and my calendar items used to pop up at the bottom right screen and stay there until I clicked on them or selected "remind me again in 5 minutes".  Now it seems to have changed so that I hear a chime, it pops up on the bottom right of my screen, but then disappears.  That is terrible!  If I'm not in front of my computer and a notification comes up, I won't know it's there.  How can I switch it back so that my notification stays on my screen until I get rid of it?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 0):

We can try to add event notifications to each calendar as below:

1.Open up your Google Calendar.

2.Click on the Gear icon.

3.Click Settings.

4.Select the calendar to be configured.

5.Scroll down to Event notifications.

6.Click the drop-down and select the type of notification you want to set.

7.Configure the time associated with the alert.

[image]

For details we can refer the articles: [How to customize your Google Calendar notifications](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-customize-your-google-calendar-notifications/)